# Suppress specific kind of warning in Javadoc with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I am using Gradle 8.1.1 to generate Javadocs. We know that passing `-Xdoclint:none` to the task can completely suppress warnings, but I just want to ignore a few rules (e.g. `no @param for <T>`). How can I achieve that?

```
task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}
```

Comment: Fine-grained control of doclint warnings isn’t currently possible.  As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javadoc.html#doclint), the only suppressable warning categories are `accessibility`, `html`, `missing`, `reference`, and `syntax`.